# Why does my phone peg the CPU every time I wake it up?

Tags: performance

This is driving me nuts. I have SeePU installed so that I can see a CPU graph on my Moto Droid. When I unlock the phone after being idle for a while, the CPU is pegged by android.process.acore and the phone is unusable for 15-45 seconds, which is an eternity when you are trying to answer the phone!

Tech details:

- Moto Droid
- OS 2.2 CyanogenMod v6 (also happens with 2.1 stock)
- Launcher: LauncherPro (also happens with DXTop, and ADW Launcher)
- No task killer

Apps:
http://www.appbrain.com/user/mark_porter/apps-on-the-phone

**UPDATE:** I un-installed most of my apps, and I seem to have licked the problem for now. I'm gonna try adding one app back a day until it gets stupid again. If I can find a particular app that causes this problem, I'll post it here

Comment: Does it still do it with Android 2.2?

Comment: It's ADW. I have the same problem with both ADW and LauncherPro. Can't find a fix other than uninstalling.

Comment: Did you ever find the offending app?

Answer (score 2):

Are you over/underclocking your CPU at all and/or using profiles?

A lot of users will underclock their CPU when the phone is sleeping, which may save battery. However, if you underclock too much (125 MHz), the phone will lag like crazy when it wakes. It is recommended to never underclock further than 250 MHz.

Aside from that, I'm not really sure anything would cause this to happen and would need more information to help you diagnose.

Comment: I don't underclock below 250, and my buddy with bone stock Moto droid has the same problem. What elese would help trouble-shooting?

Comment: A few more things: does it happen with SetCPU uninstalled? Also, how many home replacement apps/launchers do you have installed? If you have multiple and each of those has widgets, etc, that could also strain your system (and hinder battery life). Always only keep one home replacement/launcher loaded with your widgets.

Answer (score 2):

I have had a lot of pegged-CPU, laggy-phone problems with my MT3G stock Android phone. At different times, I have thought it was due to specific apps, but it usually comes back. Certain apps make it worse, Better Keyboard seemed epecially bad, but I'm not sure any one app is the root cause. I have Master Re-Set a few times, it eventually comes back. Very, very frustrating. (I use Wing Tseng's Task Manager to see CPU usage.)

Comment: I have the same issue with the MT3G except that it's rooted & running CM6.

Answer (score 2):

If it reoccurs again and you have trouble pinning down which app it is, I would recommend Watchdog (free version is more than sufficient). You can use it to to track down what is eating up CPU so you can eliminate the program directly instead of having to remove it all and swap them all in individually.

Comment: He's already said that "android.process.acore" is what's using his available CPU cycles. Watchdog and SeePU are similar in function.

Comment: Missed that, apologies. What I get for answering questions pre-coffee.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing that, just try the [WatchDog app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zomut.watchdog) which finds which apps uses a lot of memory or slow down your Android phone.