# Phone is slow to respond after waking up

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, 2.3-gingerbread, performance

Many times when I unlock my phone to wake it up, there seems to be a lot of lag shortly after.  For instance, simply trying to make a call or opening an app seems to take about 5 to 10 seconds or so.  I can't really look at the memory usage or anything because it is only within the first 10 seconds or so.  For the most part, other than this short time period, operation of the phone seems fine regarding speed.

This behavior seems to occur more frequently when I leave an app open, such as a messaging (Handcent) app or Browser.

Is there a way to identify what is slowing my phone down?

I am running a Gingerbread 2.3.3-based ROM on a Samsung Galaxy S (Captivate).

Edit to add:  Steps I've taken so far:

1. Removed any widgets
2. No longer use Live Wallpaper

Comment: Seems similar to: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/777/why-does-my-phone-peg-the-cpu-every-time-i-wake-it-up

Comment: @P.T., Yeah, you're right. didn't see that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating to a 2.3.4-based ROM that is not 2.3.3, this issue seems to be solved.  See more details in the answer to this [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14299/is-there-any-known-memory-leak-in-gingerbread-2-3-3-fixed-by-occasional-reboot).