# Is there any known memory leak in Gingerbread 2.3.3 fixed by occasional reboot? Related to battery usage?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, battery-life, performance, samsung-captivate

I notice that when I reboot my Samsung Captivate, it runs smoothly for about 2 or 3 days.  After that, I notice that there is a lot more lag with various apps, and the launcher screen is more likely to die and restart, mostly after running the browser.  After I reboot, it seems to behave fine.

Today was one of those days where I needed to restart.  I also noticed that the battery drained much more quickly today (down to 45% after 3.5 hours).  Looking at battery usage stats, Android OS used 41% of the battery.

From talking to friends, battery usage issues are fixed temporarily by a simple reboot.

From other questions on here, people who have issues with lag use various type tools like Watchdog, only to see Android OS using most of it.

Is the battery usage issue and occasional lag issues related?  Is this an issue that is fixed in 2.3.4, or a subsequent version?

Comment: I've noticed the same thing with my Droid X. A reboot fixes things but rebooting every couple of days is far from ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded to a 2.3.4 ROM.  I no longer have the battery drain issue, or the lag issue.  The question is whether or not it was the specific ROM or the 2.3.3 OS, but based on multiple links, [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16721#c2) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15057), I believe it is a 2.3.3 issue fixed in 2.3.4.